# Local cross  sections  for Unitary  group  in  a  hilbert space

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let  $U(\mathcal{H})$ be  the   group of  unitary  operators  on a  Hilbert space with  the  norm  topology. Let $H\subset U(\mathcal{H})$  be  a  closed  subgroup. 
Under  which  condidions (on  the  subgroup) is  there  a local  cross  section for  the  projection $p:U(\mathcal{H})\to U(\mathcal{H})/H$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are basically asking: When is $p \colon U(\mathcal{H}) \to U(\mathcal{H})/H$ a principal $H$-bundle. Equipped with the norm topology $U(\mathcal{H})$ is a Banach-Lie group. There is a theorem for quotients of Banach-Lie groups by Glöckner and Neeb in a paper called [Banach-Lie Quotients, Enlargibility and Universal Complexifications](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~preprint/2001/gn2001.pdf). Remark II.5 in this paper might be helpful.

To be precise they make the following definition:

- Let $G$ be a Banach-Lie group (over $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), then a Banach Lie group $H \subset G$ is called an *analytic subgroup* if the inclusion map $\iota \colon H \to G$ is smooth and $\iota_* \colon Lie(H) \to Lie(G)$ is an embedding of topological Lie algebras.
- An analytic subgroup $H \subset G$ is called a *Lie subgroup* if $\iota \colon H \to G$ is a topological embedding.

These are quite natural conditions on subgroups. In Corollary II.4 they state:

> > Suppose $G$ is a real Banach Lie group and $N$ is a closed normal subgroup of $G$. Then the topological quotient group $G/N$ can be given a real Banach Lie group structure compatible with the quotient topology if and only if $N$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$.

The important bit is now that if you have a normal Lie subgroup $N$ of a Banach Lie group $G$, then $Lie(G/N) = Lie(G) / Lie(N)$. The quotient map $q \colon G \to G/N$ induces a map of Banach spaces $Lie(G) \to Lie(G) / Lie(N)$, which has a continuous (but not necessarily linear!) section by Michael's selection theorem (sometimes called the Bartle-Graves theorem in this context, if I remember correctly). Together with the exponential map, this implies that $G \to G/N$ has local sections.

Comment: Thank  you!  Is there  a Structure  of  Banach or  Locally  convex  Lie group in  any  sense  in $U(\mathcal{H})$ for the  strong  or  the  weak  topology? 

Comment: The strong and the weak topology coincide on the unitary group of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Moreover, $U(\mathcal{H})$ is a Polish group with respect these topologies, in particular the topology is still completely metrizable.